# EF Core Web API and EF Core client app

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, ef-core-2.0

I have a Web API setup using EF Core. I have my model setup and bound to my sql server through the DBContext. I have a controller for my model. The controller defines the Get, Put, Post and Delete methods.

I am consuming the API from another application that also uses EF Core with Razor pages. I set it up to use DBContext and also created all the same models as are present in my API.

Now I'm kind of stuck on understanding how to integrate the data from my Web API calls into the EF Core DBContext setup. I can't pass my sql server connection as the Context because I want the API to handle everything data related. I want to know if this is possible. If so, how do I set it up?

As a work around for now, I am overriding the default Razor pages .cs code and making my own calls to get back the data from my API and bind it to my models. This works fine for getting data, but now I want to post or put data and I'm not sure how to access the model that I am passing into my Razor page when I submit the form. How can I access this form data that represents the model that was passed into the Razor page? I want to write my own put to send the data to my API.

Here is a snippet of the OnPost method that is called when the submit button is clicked on the Razor Page and what I want to do:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Page();
    }

    var resMsg = await DataHelper.UpdateData(1, ModelState.???) ModelState); //this calls the api to update the passed in model for the given id
}
```

Comment: You'd pass the model into your `OnPostAsync(MyClass model)`. The form name attributes will be the property names of `MyClass`. e.g. `<input name="Id" type="text" />` binds to `model.Id`.

Comment: Thanks! That addressed what I needed.